# Convert numbers to letters beyond the 26 character alphabet

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating some client side functions for a mappable spreadsheet export feature.

I'm using jQuery to manage the sort order of the columns, but each column is ordered like an Excel spreadsheet i.e. a b c d e......x y z aa ab ac ad etc etc

How can I generate a number as a letter? Should I define a fixed array of values? Or is there a dynamic way to generate this?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this

```js
    function colName(n) {
        var ordA = 'a'.charCodeAt(0);
        var ordZ = 'z'.charCodeAt(0);
        var len = ordZ - ordA + 1;
      
        var s = "";
        while(n >= 0) {
            s = String.fromCharCode(n % len + ordA) + s;
            n = Math.floor(n / len) - 1;
        }
        return s;
    }

// Example:

    for(n = 0; n < 125; n++)
            document.write(n + ":" + colName(n) + "<br>");
```

Comment: Good answer, but I would have liked to have seen an explanation behind it. Things like 97 represents small 'a' etc.

Comment: @georg Would you please explain how the base conversion works? I mean why `n = Math.floor(n / len) - 1`? Why are you subtracting `1` here? I am having a hard time getting the idea behind it. I read several answers here and there but couldn't understand why it works. Please explain :)

Comment: @YaseenMollik: hi, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/8798330/989121 for a good explanation.

Comment: `Math.floor()` is a floating point operation, also n%len was already calculated above, and that line is `n = (n - n%len) / len -1;`. In this use case it is not a performance problem, but from my point of view it is more easy to read, because no FPU op is used to get an int

Answer (score 32):

This is a very easy way:

```js
function numberToLetters(num) {
    let letters = ''
    while (num >= 0) {
        letters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'[num % 26] + letters
        num = Math.floor(num / 26) - 1
    }
    return letters
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work above 701.  But then again I don't even know if columns can get to AAA

Comment: @Cooper It works. For 701 returns "ZZ" and for 702 it returns "AAA". Then successively: "AAB", "AAC". Same as in Excel.

Answer (score 6):

```
function getColumnDescription(i) {
  const m = i % 26;
  const c = String.fromCharCode(65 + m);
  const r = i - m;
  return r > 0
    ? `${getColumnDescription((r - 1) / 26)}${c}`
    : `Column ${c}`
}
```

Usage:

```
getColumnDescription(15)
"Column P"

getColumnDescription(26)
"Column AA"

getColumnDescription(4460)
"Column FOO"
```

Answer (score 4):

Simple recursive solution:

```
function numberToColumn(n) {
  const res = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'[n % 26];
  return n >= 26 ? numberToColumn(Math.floor(n / 26) - 1) + res : res;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have your data in a two-dimensional array, e.g.

```
var data = [
  ['Day', 'score],
  ['Monday', 99],
];
```

you can map the rows/columns to spreadsheet cell numbers as follows (building on the code examples above):

```
function getSpreadSheetCellNumber(row, column) {
  let result = '';

  // Get spreadsheet column letter
  let n = column;
  while (n >= 0) {
    result = String.fromCharCode(n % 26 + 65) + result;
    n = Math.floor(n / 26) - 1;
  }

  // Get spreadsheet row number
  result += `${row + 1}`;

  return result;
};
```

E.g. the 'Day' value from data[0][0] would go in spreadsheet cell A1.

```
> getSpreadSheetCellNumber(0, 0)
> "A1"
```

This also works when you have 26+ columns:

```
> getSpreadSheetCellNumber(0, 26)
> "AA1"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use code like this, assuming that `numbers` contains the numbers of your columns. So after this code you'll get the string names for your columns:

```
var letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', ..., 'z'];
var numbers = [1, 2, 3, ...];
var columnNames = [];
for(var i=0;i<numbers.length;i++) {
    var firstLetter = parseInt(i/letters.length) == 0 ? '' : letters[parseInt(i/letters.length)];
    var secondLetter = letters[i%letters.length-1];
    columnNames.push(firstLetter + secondLetter);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. That works great but it doesn't start with just a single character i.e. a, b, c, d....x, y, z, aa, ab, ac?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative approach that relies on `.toString(26)`. It uses conversion to base-26 and then translates the characters so they are in the `a..z` range:

```js
const conv = ((base, alpha) => { // Closure for preparing the function
    const map = Object.fromEntries(Array.from(alpha, (c, i) => [c, alpha[i + 10]]));
    return n => (n + base).toString(26).replace(/o*p/, "").replace(/./g, m => map[m]);
})(parseInt("ooooooooop0", 26), "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");

// Example:
for (let n = 0; n < 29; n++) console.log(n, conv(n));
console.log("...");
for (let n = 690; n < 705; n++) console.log(n, conv(n));
```

### About the magical number

The magical value "ooooooooop0" is derived as follows:

- It is a number expressed in radix 26, in the standard way, i.e. where the ten digits also play a role, and then the first letters of the alphabet.
- The greatest "digit" in this radix 26 is "p" (the 16<sup>th</sup> letter of the Latin alphabet), and "o" is the second greatest.
- The magical value is formed by a long enough series of the one-but-greatest digit, followed by the greatest digit and ended by a 0.
- As JavaScript integer numbers max out around `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` (greater integers numbers would suffer from rounding errors), there is no need to have a longer series of "o" than was selected. We can see that `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER.toString(26)` has 12 digits, so precision is ensured up to 11 digits in radix 26, meaning we need 9 "o".
- This magical number ensures that if we add units to it (in radix 26), we will always have a representation which starts with a series of "o" and then a "p". That is because at some point the last digit will wrap around to 0 again, and the "p" will also wrap around to 0, bringing the preceding "o" to "p". And so we have this invariant that the number always starts with zero or more "o" and then a "p".

### More generic

The above magic number could be derived via code, and we could make it more generic by providing the target alphabet. The length of that target alphabet then also directly determines the radix (i.e. the number of characters in that string).

Here is the same output generated as above, but with a more generic function:

```js
function createConverter(targetDigits) {
    const radix = targetDigits.length,
          alpha = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz",
          map = Object.fromEntries(Array.from(alpha, 
                (src, i) => [src, targetDigits[i]]
          )), 
          base = parseInt((alpha[radix-1]+'0').padStart(
               Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER.toString(radix).length - 1, alpha[radix-2]
          ), radix),
          trimmer = RegExp("^" + alpha[radix-2] + "*" + alpha[radix-1]);
    return n => (n + base).toString(radix)
                          .replace(trimmer, "")
                          .replace(/./g, m => map[m]);
}

// Example:
const conv = createConverter("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
for (let n = 0; n < 29; n++) console.log(n, conv(n));
console.log("...");
for (let n = 690; n < 705; n++) console.log(n, conv(n));
```

This can now easily be adapted to use a more reduced target alphabet (like without the letters "l" and "o"), giving a radix of 24 instead of 26:

```js
function createConverter(targetDigits) {
    const radix = targetDigits.length,
          alpha = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz",
          map = Object.fromEntries(Array.from(alpha, 
                (src, i) => [src, targetDigits[i]]
          )), 
          base = parseInt((alpha[radix-1]+'0').padStart(
               Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER.toString(radix).length - 1, alpha[radix-2]
          ), radix),
          trimmer = RegExp("^" + alpha[radix-2] + "*" + alpha[radix-1]);
    return n => (n + base).toString(radix)
                          .replace(trimmer, "")
                          .replace(/./g, m => map[m]);
}

// Example without "l" and "o" in target alphabet:
const conv = createConverter("abcdefghijkmnpqrstuvwxyz");
for (let n = 0; n < 29; n++) console.log(n, conv(n));
console.log("...");
for (let n = 690; n < 705; n++) console.log(n, conv(n));
```

Comment: Intriguing approach, however, how is the ooooooop0 calculated? It's a bit unclear how this solution should be modified if we wanted to use an arbitrary alphabet that is not base 26 (e.g., removing O and L so they aren't confused with numbers).

Comment: Nice! Would this also apply to a larger target alphabet or just a reduced one?

Comment: Also, I have to say: this solution is absolutely brilliant.

Comment: It would work up to a radix of 36, i.e. it is limited by what `toString` and `parseInt` can deal with using their optional *radix* argument.

Answer (score 0):

This covers the range from 1 to 1000.  Beyond that I haven't checked.

```
function colToletters(num) {
  let a = " ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
  if (num < 27) return a[num % a.length];
  if (num > 26) {
    num--;
    let letters = ''
    while (num >= 0) {
      letters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'[num % 26] + letters
      num = Math.floor(num / 26) - 1
    }
    return letters;
  }
}
```

I could be wrong but I've checked the other functions in this answer and they seem to fail at 26 which should be Z.  Remember there are 26 letters in the alphabet not 25.

Answer (score 0):

An ES6 2Liner inspried by https://stackoverflow.com/a/71713806/22468906

```
const a2z = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
const day2Col = n => (n > 26 ? day2Col((n-1)/26|0) : '') + a2z[(n-1)%26]
```

Need to note that many of above answers, even the accepted answer, are wrong that AAA should come from an odd number (thus wrong for 702 -> AAA)

Referring to [this exhausted list](https://www.vishalon.net/blog/excel-column-letter-to-number-quick-reference), 702 should give ZZ, 703 then AAA