# Converting letter grade GPA to number grade using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-events

I am developing a web application that takes letter grades like A, A-, B etc as form inputs and converts it to number grades (A == 4.0, A- == 3.7 and so on) on the backend. I cant figure out how to convert it (using JavaScript) and display the grade on the HTML. Here is my HTML code:

```
<td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="cs520" placeholder="letter grade"/></td>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="cs550" placeholder="letter grade"/></td>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="cs571" placeholder="letter grade"/></td>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="cs575" placeholder="letter grade"/></td>
<td><span id="finalGPA"></span></br><input type="button" onClick=add() value="Submit"> </td>
```

I found something similar on [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8240637/convert-numbers-to-letters-beyond-the-26-character-alphabet) but it seems to not solve my issue. Can someone help me with the Javascript code?

Comment: Show your try...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start by adding `grade` classes to your input elements so they can be easily identified. I would, perhaps, add a `pattern` regex attribute to them too so that if something other than a grade is added it will show an error. Finally, remove the inline JS from the button.

For the JavaScript, pick up the elements you'll need with `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll`, and add an event listener to the button that calls the function when it's clicked.

Second, create an object that maps the grade letters to a score. I've only used A-E here, but pick whatever is appropriate for your application.

Finally, use `reduce` to iterate over the input values, make them uppercase if they're not already, return the score from the grade map, and add it to the `textContent` of the final score element. You can, of course, use a simple for-loop for the iteration if that's what you're more comfortable with, but `reduce` is a good fit for this example.

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.grade');
const final = document.querySelector('#finalGPA');
const button = document.querySelector('input[type="button"]');
button.addEventListener('click', checkGrades, false);

const gradeMap = {
  A: 4,
  B: 3,
  C: 2,
  D: 1,
  E: 0
}

function checkGrades() {
  final.textContent = [...inputs].reduce((total, grade) => {
    return total += gradeMap[grade.value.toUpperCase()];
  }, 0);
}
```

```html
<td><input type="text" pattern="^[a-eA-E]{1}[+|-]?$" class="form-control grade" id="cs520" placeholder="letter grade" /></td>
<td><input type="text" pattern="^[a-eA-E]{1}[+|-]?$" class="form-control grade" id="cs550" placeholder="letter grade" /></td>
<td><input type="text" pattern="^[a-eA-E]{1}[+|-]?$" class="form-control grade" id="cs571" placeholder="letter grade" /></td>
<td><input type="text" pattern="^[a-eA-E]{1}[+|-]?$" class="form-control grade" id="cs575" placeholder="letter grade" /></td>
<td><span id="finalGPA"></span><br/>
<input type="button" value="Submit" /></td>
```

MDN resources

- [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
- [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)
- [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)
- [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) for information on the pattern attribute
- [`Spread syntax`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)

Answer (score 2):

I would store the letter grades and their numerical values ('A' === 4.0, 'A-' === 3.7, etc) in an object so that way they can be linked through key-value pairs like so:

```
var grades = {
    'A': 4.0,
    'A-': 3.7,
    // insert rest of grades here
}
```

Then, using the DOM, you can capture the user input. As an example:

```
var userGrade = document.getElementById('#cs520').value
```

Or, if you're using jQuery, you can capture the user input this way:

```
var userGrade = $('#cs520').val();
```

Once you have these set up, you can make a function that converts userGrade to its corresponding value in the grades object, then execute some calculation to get the overall GPA.

```
var GPA = 0; 

function calculateGPA () {
    // adds numerical value of userGrade to GPA for future calculation
    var gradeVal = grades[userGrade];
    GPA += gradeVal;
}
```

However, I think this calculation will depend on what kind of GPA you'll want to calculate (i.e. regular, weighted, by subject, etc.). Hope this helps!

Comment: It doesn't look like the OP is using jQuery. Perhaps try a vanilla JS approach? Also: `grade[userGrade]` should be `grades[userGrade]` according to your code.

Comment: @Andy thanks for point that out! I've since edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As I understood your question, you are taking the Grades like A, A-... pass them to the backend. You are doing some calculations using the grade numbers and send back the result on UI.

You can maintain an Object like

```
var grades = { 
   "A": 4.0,
   "A-": 3.7,
    ...
}
```

You can retrieve the grade number like `grades["A"]`

Comment: It's just an object, not a JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

One way you could go about doing it would be to first figure out what each letter corresponds to. You could take input for each letter grade, then run a conditional statement to see which one it matches, and assign that variable the GPA. Something along the lines of

```
Input: A
If (input1 == a) {
value1 == 4.0}
else if (input1 == b) {
value1 == 3.7}
```

And then at the end you can average all of your input, if you do something similar to the code I provided, look into a way of doing it with a for loop or something similar so you don't have to write out that long code.

Answer (score 0):

You can get input values like this,
`var input = document.getElementById("input_id").value;`

and you can define the grade and points like this.
`let totalPoints=0;`
`let a_Plus=4.0;`
`let a_minus=3.7;`ect..

then with the if confition you can get the values for tha grades.
`if(input=="A+"){`
`totalPoints=totalPoints+a_Plus;`
`}`
With nested if condition you can do whatever you want.