# DataTables Excel export with styles

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I am using DataTables compatible with Bootstrap. In a page I export table in Excel using “excelHtml5” and everything goes well.

In my case I want to set specific background colors on some cells, with “excelHtml5” there is a list of built in styles that we can use and I was able to apply them =>

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable({
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [{
            extend: 'excelHtml5',
            customize: function(xlsx) {
                var sheet = xlsx.xl.worksheets['sheet1.xml'];
 
                $('row c', sheet).each( function () {
                    // Get the value
                    if ( $('is t', this).text() == 'New York' ) {
                        $(this).attr( 's', '20' );
                    }
                });
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

These built in styles are not enough for me, when I searched a lot I found responses that shows how to add new styles by modifying "xl/styles.xml" section in “buttons.html5.js” file, tried with many ways but no success I think there is some sort of internal cache or I am editing the wrong file.

So I found after another way by using this library https://github.com/pjjonesnz/datatables-buttons-excel-styles which I found very flexible and helpful, the thing here is I can create new styles but I can’t use them depending on the text value of the cell, they offer just a conditioning system for numeric values and operators “equal” “lessThan” ….

So anyone can help me with this, a trick or other way to apply specific styles on exported xlsx files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**

The below process may be suitable for your needs, but you may prefer to avoid making manual changes, by using a different approach:

[jQuery datatable export to excel with cell() background color](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73793683/12567365)

This approach does not require manual file editing.

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

Looking at your comment:

> "*how to add new styles by modifying "xl/styles.xml" section in “buttons.html5.js” file, tried with many ways but no success*"

Here is a step-by-step guide to how I edited my local copy of the `buttons.html5.js` file to add a new custom style.

1. I first went to the DataTables [download page](https://datatables.net/download) and downloaded the files I need.
2. I used the related script tags in the `<head>` section of the page - for example:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="buttons/Buttons-2.2.3/js/buttons.html5.js"></script>`

And I made sure my files were in the expected location relative to my HTML file containing my DataTable.

3. I edited my `buttons.html5.js` file as follows... You need to get this *exactly* right...

What I will do in the next steps is:

- add one new font style to define a new font color (a shade of green).
- add one new fill style to define a new cell background color (a shade of yellow).
- add one new cell formatting style which uses the above colors.

4. I added one new font to the `<fonts>` section, at the end:

```xml
            '<fonts count="6" x14ac:knownFonts="1">'+
                '<font>'+
                    '<sz val="11" />'+
                    '<name val="Calibri" />'+
                '</font>'+
                '<font>'+
                    '<sz val="11" />'+
                    '<name val="Calibri" />'+
                    '<color rgb="FFFFFFFF" />'+
                '</font>'+
                '<font>'+
                    '<sz val="11" />'+
                    '<name val="Calibri" />'+
                    '<b />'+
                '</font>'+
                '<font>'+
                    '<sz val="11" />'+
                    '<name val="Calibri" />'+
                    '<i />'+
                '</font>'+
                '<font>'+
                    '<sz val="11" />'+
                    '<name val="Calibri" />'+
                    '<u />'+
                '</font>'+
                
                // added font ID 5:
                '<font>'+
                    '<sz val="11" />'+
                    '<name val="Calibri" />'+
                    '<color rgb="FF548235" />'+
                '</font>'+
                
            '</fonts>'+
```

5. I incremented the related count (at the top of that section) from `count="5"` to `count="6"`.

That RGB string `FF548235` represents the color `548235`, which is a shade of green, with an alpha channel of `FF` (meaning opaque). Note how the `FF` of the alpha channel comes *before* the RGB code.

6. I repeated the process for the `<fills>` section, adding one new fill color:

```xml
            '<fills count="7">'+
                '<fill>'+
                    '<patternFill patternType="none" />'+
                '</fill>'+
                '<fill>'+ // Excel appears to use this as a dotted background regardless of values but
                    '<patternFill patternType="none" />'+ // to be valid to the schema, use a patternFill
                '</fill>'+
                '<fill>'+
                    '<patternFill patternType="solid">'+
                        '<fgColor rgb="FFD9D9D9" />'+
                        '<bgColor indexed="64" />'+
                    '</patternFill>'+
                '</fill>'+
                '<fill>'+
                    '<patternFill patternType="solid">'+
                        '<fgColor rgb="FFD99795" />'+
                        '<bgColor indexed="64" />'+
                    '</patternFill>'+
                '</fill>'+
                '<fill>'+
                    '<patternFill patternType="solid">'+
                        '<fgColor rgb="ffc6efce" />'+
                        '<bgColor indexed="64" />'+
                    '</patternFill>'+
                '</fill>'+
                '<fill>'+
                    '<patternFill patternType="solid">'+
                        '<fgColor rgb="ffc6cfef" />'+
                        '<bgColor indexed="64" />'+
                    '</patternFill>'+
                '</fill>'+
                
                // added fill ID 6:
                '<fill>'+
                    '<patternFill patternType="solid">'+
                        '<fgColor rgb="ffffc000" />'+
                        '<bgColor indexed="64" />'+
                    '</patternFill>'+
                '</fill>'+
                
            '</fills>'+
```

The fill color is `ffffc000`, which is `ff` for the alpha channel, followed by the RGB code of `ffc000` - which is a shade of darker green.

7. As with the fonts section, I incremented the related count (at the top of that section). This time, it changed from count="6" to count="7".

NOTE that the font ID and fill ID are 1 less than the total count, because the IDs start at zero - so that is why the 7th `<fill>` has an ID of 6.

You do not provide these IDs in the XML. Excel determines the IDs based on the position of the font (or fill) within the overall fonts (or fills) list.

But you need to know the correct ID numbers so you can use them in the next step...

8. I added a new style at the end of the `<cellXfs>` section:

```xml
                // added xf ID 68:
                '<xf numFmtId="0" fontId="5" fillId="6" borderId="0" applyFont="1" applyFill="1" applyBorder="1"/>'+
```

This is where I use the font and fill IDs: `fontId="5" fillId="6"`.

9. I also needed to increment the overall style count from `count="68"` to `count="69"`.

---

After saving all the above changes, I can now use that new style - which is style ID 68.

I used the code from your question for this:

```js
var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
  dom: "Brftip",
  buttons: [{
    extend: 'excelHtml5',
    customize: function(xlsx) {
        var sheet = xlsx.xl.worksheets['sheet1.xml'];
 
        $('row c', sheet).each( function () {
            // Get the value
            if ( $('is t', this).text() == 'New York' ) {
                $(this).attr( 's', '68' );
            }
        });
    }
  }]
} );
```

Note the `attr( 's', '68' )` above.

Using my test data, this generates the following:

[image]

---

The big downside with this approach is that you have manually edited the DataTables JavaScript - and **those changes will be lost** when you upgrade DataTables to a newer version. You will have to repeat the above edits.

You can avoid this by automating these edits in your DataTable's JavaScript code using `customize: function( xlsx )`.

That function gives you access to the Excel object (`xlsx`) inside which all the spreadsheet's data and styles are stored.

That is a larger, more complicated programming task.

But if you are interested, you can see an example showing a similar approach here: [JQuery Datatable Excel export number format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67340599/12567365) and also in various other questions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks’ a lot Andrew, Appreciate the time and the efforts you had given to my question. Actually I was doing the right thing ( respecting the Ids and count of new styles … ), just I was targeting the wrong file, my primary datatables.js file was downloaded with the code of “buttons.html5.js” included, so my edited code was overwritten