# Datatable export - header formating

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel, datatable, export

I am using datatable plugin, working on Jquery. I want to do header styling on export excel. set background color as dark blue, with font size=14, font color=white and top right alignment.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73793683/12567365) which shows you how to set the font color and cell fill color. You can also control the font size with a small additional change to the code in that answer. You can do some more research for top right alignment.