# Map through array, create a key-value pair for each element, and give key of an alphabet letter to each pair

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects (I don't know how many object, maybe 3, maybe 10)
example:

```
const data = [
  {name: 'Jane', age: 25},
  {name:'Luke', age: 55},
  {name:'Martha', age: '16'},
  ...and so on
]
```

now I want to map through this array and create a key-value pair for each, and as a key I want to use a letter of alphabet (starting with c).
expected result is:

```
{
  c:{name: 'Jane', age: 25}, 
  d:{name:'Luke', age: 55},
  e:{name:'Martha', age: '16'}
  ...and so on
}
```

How to achieve that ?

I am using JS & React

Comment: What happens if there were more than 24 objects?

Comment: How does `c` correspond to object  `{name: 'Jane', age: 25}` just understanding your reasoning here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily achieve the result using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [String.fromCharCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode).

[ASCII CODE](http://sticksandstones.kstrom.com/appen.html) of `c` is `99`

```js
const data = [
  { name: "Jane", age: 25 },
  { name: "Luke", age: 55 },
  { name: "Martha", age: "16" },
];

const result = data.reduce((acc, curr, i) => {
  acc[String.fromCharCode(99 + i)] = curr;
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

Disregarding the why, and the limitations of using letters...

You can map the array, and create a tuples of `[letter, object]`, and then convert them to an object using `Object.fromEntries()`.

To create the letter, add 99 to the current index value (`i`) to get the current letters ascii code, and then convert it to a letter using `String.charFromCode()`.

```js
const data = [
  {name: 'Jane', age: 25},
  {name:'Luke', age: 55},
  {name:'Martha', age: '16'},
]

const result = Object.fromEntries(
  data.map((o, i) => [String.fromCharCode(i + 99), o])
)

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that... (with a simple reduce)

```js
const data =
  [ { name: 'Jane',  age: 25  }
  , { name:'Luke',   age: 55  }
  , { name:'Martha', age: '16'}
  ]
let lCod  = 'c'.charCodeAt(0)
const res = data.reduce((r,o)=>(r[String.fromCharCode(lCod++)]=o,r),{})

console.log (res)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```

> if your array size is bigger than 24...
> with the help of [**georg**'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8240637/convert-numbers-to-letters-beyond-the-26-character-alphabet)

```js
const data = 
  [ { name: 'nam_0',  age: 0 }, { name: 'nam_1',  age: 1 }, { name: 'nam_2',  age: 2 }, { name: 'nam_3',  age: 3 }, { name: 'nam_4',  age: 4 }
  , { name: 'nam_5',  age: 5 }, { name: 'nam_6',  age: 6 }, { name: 'nam_7',  age: 7 }, { name: 'nam_8',  age: 8 }, { name: 'nam_9',  age: 9 }
  , { name: 'nam_10', age:10 }, { name: 'nam_11', age:11 }, { name: 'nam_12', age:12 }, { name: 'nam_13', age:13 }, { name: 'nam_14', age:14 }
  , { name: 'nam_15', age:15 }, { name: 'nam_16', age:16 }, { name: 'nam_17', age:17 }, { name: 'nam_18', age:18 }, { name: 'nam_19', age:19 }
  , { name: 'nam_20', age:20 }, { name: 'nam_21', age:21 }, { name: 'nam_22', age:22 }, { name: 'nam_23', age:23 }, { name: 'nam_24', age:24 }
  , { name: 'nam_25', age:25 }, { name: 'nam_26', age:26 }, { name: 'nam_27', age:27 }, { name: 'nam_28', age:28 }, { name: 'nam_29', age:29 }
  ] 
, cName = ((lZero = 'c')=>
  {
  let[a,z,Ln] = [...'az'+lZero].map(c=>c.charCodeAt(0)), mod = z-a+1;
  Ln -= a;
  return ()=>
    {
    let n = Ln++, s = '';
    while (n>=0)
      { 
      s = String.fromCharCode(n % mod + a ) + s
      n = Math.floor(n / mod) - 1;
      }
    return s
  } })()
, res = data.reduce((r,o)=>(r[cName()]=o,r),{})

console.log (res)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```